# To customize the content type of basic page of Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I am now using Drupal7.12, How to make the basic page contains no "read more" link on the bottom of the ariticle? and i want its title be a plain text other than hyperlink. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

hi the process is very tedious to be written down here however you can follow this http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=138 link to get help.

It worked for me hope it sorts out your issue too.